# Custom property decorator that behaves like @property?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'd like to create a custom Python decorator that will 1) check the value of a class attribute `my_attribute` before running the function, and 2) turn the class method into a property. I can achieve this as follows:

```
def my_decorator(f):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.my_attribute is None:
            raise ValueError('No location set to model.')

        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class MyClass:
    my_attribute = None

    @property
    @my_decorator
    def my_method():
        return self. my_attribute
```

I'd like to know how I can edit the definition of `my_decorator` so that it makes the wrapped method a property. Essentially I'd like to avoid the use of `@property` and `@my_decorator` for each method, letting me write the class definition as

```
class MyClass:
    my_attribute = None

    @my_new_decorator
    def my_method():
        return self. my_attribute
```

I've looked up the declaration of the builtin `@property` decorator, but it's defined as a class and wasn't much help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you changed your decorator definition to look like this?

```
def my_decorator(f):
    @property
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.my_attribute is None:
            raise ValueError('No location set to model.')

        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

That should make the returned function behave like a property, and keep your custom error handling.

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to keep/use also the original `my_decorator`, one could create a `my_decorator_property` as following:

```py
def my_decorator_property(f):
    @property
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return my_decorator(f)(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```